# How to fix "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Projection' mapbox-gl" error in vs code using typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mapbox-gl-js, definitelytyped

I am trying to setup mapbox-gl using typescript. I get the following error in VS Code when I try to set the projection value according to the docs.
Basically:

```
 map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'mapbox',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12',
      projection: 'naturalEarth'
    })
```

Even the suggested default value is 'mercator', which is clearly a string.
Everything works correctly when running the code, but how can i tell vs code to accept that a string is correct there?

the output from npm list is this:

```
mapbox-gl@2.15.0
```

Also, this is accepted by vs code:

```
map.setProjection('globe')
```

which works as good as the other solution, i would still prefer an answer why my original is marked as an error by vs code, especially given that it's a verbatim copy from the docs and works fine when actually running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is because the DefinitelyTyped package for mapbox-gl is just not that "up-to-date". You're using `mapbox-gl@2.15.0`, but at the time of this writing. mapbox-gl doesn't publish its own types, but the types are available from [the DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), which is where I'm assuming you're grabbing your types. Whenever you grab types from there, ideally, you'd be grabbing the types package with matching major and minor version numbers for the version of the package that it provides typings for (see [How do Definitely Typed package versions relate to versions of the corresponding library?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library)). Ex. ideally, right now, you'd be doing `npm i -D '@types/mapbox-gl@~2.15'`. Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the latest version of `@types/mapbox-gl` is 2.7.11. Now, when you look at [the changelog for mapbox-gl, you'll see that the feature you're using was added in v2.9.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#290). That's why you aren't getting types for it. Feel free to submit a Pull Request to the DefinitelyTyped project to add typings for v2.9 of mapbox-gl.

Answer (score 0):

A projection should be the type of ProjectionSpecification object, not a string.

Please refer to the code snippet and [this article](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/projections/).

```ts
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    style: {
        version: 8,
        name: 'My Projected Style',
        sources: {
            // ...
        },
        layers: [
            // ...
        ],
        projection: {
            name: 'equalEarth'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: um what? https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/projections/#define-a-projection-as-a-map-constructor-option ??

Comment: container: 'map'

Comment: I just copied verbatim the lines user posted? A string definitely works there according to the docs.

Comment: If you're using `react-map-gl`, this is the solution. It expects an object type for passing the projection prop. It does not accept a string.

Answer (score -1):

That's what worked for me:

projection as unknown as Projection

```
const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(30);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(50);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1.5);
  const [projection, setProjection] = useState("globe");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) return; // initialize map only once
    const map: any = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current!,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11",
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom,
      projection: projection as unknown as Projection,
    });
    mapRef.current = map;
    map.on("load", function () {
      const setFog = () =>
        map.setFog({
          // range: [-1, 2],
          // "horizon-blend": 0.3,
          color: "gray",
          // "high-color": "#add8e6",
          // "space-color": "black",
          // "star-intensity": 10.0,
        });
      setFog();
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).